# SQL Error [42601]: ERROR - Using Multiple update in dynamic sql

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, amazon-redshift, dynamic-sql

Trying to update a table using stored proc. Getting error as

```
SQL Error [42601]: ERROR: query "SELECT  'update view.recon_dashboard 
    set dlv_count = (select count(*) from ' ||  $1  || ') where id='||  $2 , 'set alv_count = (select count(*) from ' ||  $3  || ') where id='||  $4 , CASE WHEN  $5  is not null then 'set tgt_count = (select count(*) from ' ||  $6  || ') where id='||  $7  end" returned 3 columns
  Where: PL/pgSQL function "sp_count_recon_refresh" line 7 at execute statement
```

1)I have a table recon_dashboard for which i loop through values of each column tgt,alv,dlv and query the db to fetch the count and update the recon_dashboard table. It is working when i update a single value in update statement like : execute 'update ca_adhoc_view.recon_dashboard set dlv_count = (select count(*) from ' || f.dlv  || ') where id='|| f.id;
but it is throwing error when trying to updaate multiple columns in update statement.

```
create or replace procedure view.refresh_sp()
    language plpgsql as
$$
declare 
    f record;
BEGIN
    for f in select tgt,alv,dlv,id from view.recon_dashboard
    loop
    raise notice '% -#',f.dlv;
    execute 'update view.recon_dashboard 
    set dlv_count = (select count(*) from ' || f.dlv  || ') where id='|| f.id,
    'set alv_count = (select count(*) from ' || f.alv  || ') where id='|| f.id,
    CASE 
        WHEN f.alv is not null then
    'set tgt_count = (select count(*) from ' || f.tgt  || ') where id='|| f.id
    end;
end loop;
END;
$$;
```

Comment: Redshift or Postgres? Those are two very different databases

Comment: An UPDATE only needs a **single** SET keyword.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Postgres